# Solving non quadratic matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to divide two 3x1 matrices, so `np.linalg.inv` won't work anymore and I have to use `np.lingalg.inv` to use the vector/matrices equation, but I don't know how to apply the operator in this case.
The problem is located at line 57 (A, B =) and line 58 (X =). Maybe there is an easier way to solve all of this.

```
import numpy as np
import math

p1=float(input("p1="))
p2=float(input("p2="))
p3=float(input("p3="))
a1=float(input("a1="))
a2=float(input("a2="))
a3=float(input("a3="))
q1=float(input("q1="))
q2=float(input("q2="))
q3=float(input("q3="))
b1=float(input("b1="))
b2=float(input("b2="))
b3=float(input("b3="))

def vector(p1,p2,p3,a1,a2,a3,q1,q2,q3,b1,b2,b3):
    #Check if true
    #line 49++

    #Schnittwinkel
    ma = abs(a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3)
    if ma == 0:
        print("Orthogonal")
    m1 = math.sqrt(a1**2+a2**2+a3**2)
    m2 = math.sqrt(b1**2+b2**2+b3**2)
    cosg = ma/(m1*m2)
    g = math.acos(cosg)/math.pi*180
    print "Schnittwinkel:",g

    #a kreuz b
    x = a2*b3-a3*b2
    y = a3*b1-a1*b3
    z = a1*b2-a2*b1

    #Kuerzen
    if x%2 == 0 and y%2 == 0 and z%2 == 0:
        x = x/2
        y = y/2
        z = z/2
    elif x%3 == 0 and y%3 == 0 and z%3 == 0:
        x = x/3
        y = y/3
        z = z/3
    print "N(",x,"|",y,"|",z,")"

vector(p1,p2,p3,a1,a2,a3,q1,q2,q3,b1,b2,b3)

pq1 = q1-p1
pq2 = q2-p2
pq3 = q3-p3

my_list = [[a1,a2,a3],[-b1,-b2,-b3]]
A = np.array(my_list)
B = np.array([pq1,pq2,pq3])
A, B = np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)
X = np.linalg.inv(A).dot(B)

print(X)
```

(I want to put the last part in the main function, I'm just testing it)

The answers will surely help me in the future with other matrice problems, so I would be very thankful for great comment. ^^

[idea of how to solve vector/matrices equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBLku.png)

Comment: Sorry for probably not getting it, but what exactly do you want to calculate?

Comment: Input are matrices `A, B, P, Q` what should the output be? Where do `r` and `s` come from?

Comment: @RolandDeschain So: I have two vectorial equations (in a 3D space). I want to set equal equation 1 (support vector p with r * direction vector a) with equation 2 (support vector q with r * direction vector b) to see if they intersect. IF that is true, then the program should continue with calculating the cutting angle and the normal vector. (this part is working fine, i tested it. I just need the If condition to work correctly.)
Edit: r and s are just coefficients which i have to solve for like in a linear system of equation (ax + by = c)